# download s&p data in yahoo or google with SAS

Tags: sas

I would like to download daily s&p data every day so I can plot s&P returns in SAS.. Is there a way to download  S&P files (from yahoo or google) with SAS ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, in fact, here's a whole [SUGI](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi28/073-28.pdf) about it.

Comment: there is warning: apparent symbolic reference F not resolved. when i do filename in url 'http://finance.yahoo.com:80/d/quotes.txt?s=YHOO+IBM+HPQ&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.txt';